# How to specify a file type for resumable.js uploader?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fileapi, resume-upload, resumablejs

I want [resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js) (file uploader) to only open a file picker for a particular file type, like mp4 or mp3.

How to specify a file type for resumable.js uploader?

Answer (score 4):

You have the option `fileType` you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/23/resumable.js#full-documentation). `fileType`  default is `[]` but in your case should be `fileType: ['mp3', 'mp4']`.

```
var resumable = new Resumable({
  ...
  fileType: ['mp3', 'mp4'],
  ...
});
```

You can see a working example in https://jsfiddle.net/atomic/wn2uq53d/2/